# SENSENET 6.5.2.8421 installation from package fails due to SQL SYNTAX ERROR

Tags: sql-server-2008, sensenet

I have the following stack:

- .NET 4.5.1
- IIS 7.5
- MSSQL SERVER 2008 EXPRESS SP 4
- VISUAL  STUDIO 2013 UPDATE 5
- Windows 2007 SP1
- SENSENET 6.5.2.8421

I tried to install SENSENET importing the package using the deploy option within IIS, but when creating the data base this shows up:

```
  Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentDetailedClientServerException: Error durante la ejecución del script de la base de datos. El error ocurrió entre las siguientes líneas del script: "1061" y "1201". El registro detallado podría tener más información acerca del error. El comando comenzaba con lo siguiente:
"IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.views WHERE objec"
 Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de '!'. http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=178587  Obtenga más información en: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_SQL_EXECUTION_FAILURE. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de '!'.
   en System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   en System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   en System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   en System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   en System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async)
   en System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(DbAsyncResult result, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe)
   en System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   en Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DBStatementInfo.Execute(DbConnection connection, DbTransaction transaction, DeploymentBaseContext baseContext, Int32 timeout)
   --- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la excepción interna ---
   en Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DBStatementInfo.Execute(DbConnection connection, DbTransaction transaction, DeploymentBaseContext baseContext, Int32 timeout)
   en Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DBConnectionWrapper.ExecuteSql(DBStatementInfo sqlStatement, DeploymentBaseContext baseContext, Int32 timeout)
   en Microsoft.Web.Deployment.SqlScriptToDBProvider.AddHelper(DeploymentObject source, Boolean whatIf)
   en Microsoft.Web.Deployment.SqlScriptToDBProvider.Add(DeploymentObject source, Boolean whatIf)
   en Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.AddChild(DeploymentObject source, Int32 position, DeploymentSyncContext syncContext)
   en Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.HandleAddChild(DeploymentObject destParent, DeploymentObject sourceObject, Int32 position)
   en Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.SyncChildrenOrder(DeploymentObject dest, DeploymentObject source)
   en Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.SyncChildren(DeploymentObject dest, DeploymentObject source)
   en Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.SyncChildrenOrder(DeploymentObject dest, DeploymentObject source)
   en Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.SyncChildren(DeploymentObject dest, DeploymentObject source)
   en Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.ProcessSync(DeploymentObject destinationObject, DeploymentObject sourceObject)
   en Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.SyncToInternal(DeploymentObject destObject, DeploymentSyncOptions syncOptions, PayloadTable payloadTable, ContentRootTable contentRootTable, Nullable`1 syncPassId, String syncSessionId)
   en Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.SyncTo(DeploymentProviderOptions providerOptions, DeploymentBaseOptions baseOptions, DeploymentSyncOptions syncOptions)
   en Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.SyncTo(String provider, String path, DeploymentBaseOptions baseOptions, DeploymentSyncOptions syncOptions)
   en Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.SyncTo(DeploymentWellKnownProvider provider, String path, DeploymentBaseOptions baseOptions, DeploymentSyncOptions syncOptions)
   en Microsoft.Web.Deployment.UI.InstallProgressWizardPage.OnWorkerDoWork(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
   en System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.OnDoWork(DoWorkEventArgs e)
   en System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.WorkerThreadStart(Object argument)
```

Oviously, the installation fails.

Comment: This is installation issue with SenseNet. Nothing to do with database administartion.

Comment: @TT.: This is at least the second time I can see you advise someone post their question on a different site (on DBA in both cases, as it happens) and the OP goes and does just that, posting the question at the other site. But that is cross-posting and is wrong, so please don't do that. Instead, if you strongly believe the question belongs elsewhere, you can flag (or vote, when you reach 3K rep) it for *migration*, preferably letting the OP know about what you've done as well, so that they don't cross-post.

Comment: @AndriyM OK. Thanks for that. You make a good point. I will refrain from doing that in the future.

Comment: @YperSillyCubeᵀᴹ You are right, I misread that. Mae Culpa! =) I will remove my comment.

Comment: Well the exception is rather clear on the problem. There's a SQL syntax error around an exclamation mark (`!`) between lines "1061" and "1201". That's probably in a script that is part of the SENSENET installation. You probably best check the minimum requirements for installing SENSENET. If you feel you have met all requirements, you should report this error to the creators of SENSENET.

Answer (score 1):

The cause is most likely a SQL method (IIF) that is not available in your version of SQL Server. You can either try to install SenseNet on a newer server or download a **newer SensNet package**, because in the next version (**6.5.3+**) the script above was converted to be compatible with older SQL servers.